# Typescript errors while passing parameter to res.status().json()

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have only been using Typescript for a few days...so I'm still learning (by forcing myself to code in Typescript by converting some existing JS code to TS)...

In my code:

```
res.status(200).json({ user: data.user })
```

I get a red squiggly underling under `user:data.user`
and the error that accompanies that is:

> Argument of type '{ user: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Data'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'user' does not exist in type 'Data'.ts(2345)

Then I got another line of code that uses res.status().json as well:

```
res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: msgString.toString(),
                })
```

and again I have a red squiqqly underline under `message: msgString.toString()`

and the error that accompanies that is:

> Argument of type '{ message: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Data'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'message' does not exist in type 'Data'.ts(2345)

How do I convert these lines properly to Typescript so there won't be any errors or warnings showing???

Here is the whole code

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

import { API_URL } from '@/config/index'
import cookie from 'cookie'

type Data = {
    name: string
}

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
    // res.status(200).json({ name: 'SIGN UP' })

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        console.log('POST POST POST')
        const { username, email, password } = req.body

        console.log('/api/login.js')
        console.log(req.body)

        const strapiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/auth/local/register`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })

        const data = await strapiRes.json()

        console.log('data', data)

        if (strapiRes.ok) {
            console.log('strapiRes.ok')
            // @todo - Set cookie

            //Set cookie
            res.setHeader(
                'Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('token', data.jwt, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // a week
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/',
                })
            )
            res.status(200).json({ user: data.user })
        } else {
            console.log('else of strapiRes.ok')

            console.log('errors', data.error.details)

            if (data.error.details.errors) {
                console.log('x', data.error.details.errors)

                var msgString = data.error.details.errors.map((x) => {
                    console.log('x', x)

                    return x.message
                })

                console.log('msgString', msgString)
                res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: msgString.toString(),
                })
            } else {
                res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: data.error.message,
                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST'])
        res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${req.method} not allowed` })
    }
}
```

Comment: Which modules are you using? Please show the import / require lines.

Comment: hi ok I have edited the post to show everything...

Comment: Change your `name` field in type `Data` to `message`.

Comment: ok @coderpc that solved the errors for res.status(data.error.status).json({
                    message: msgString.toString(),
                }).  but what about for res.status(200).json({ user: data.user }) ???

Comment: You might have to add `user: string` or what ever that `data.user` type is in `Data`. So, your `Data` should look like this - `type Data = { message: string, user: any
}`

Comment: user : string and user: any and user :object I have all tried and it still errors and when I add it then suddenly the message also gets errors now again....

Comment: Ok, how about changing the `user` to `message`? Do this `res.status(200).json({ message: data.user })` And, change the `Data` type to `type Data = {message: string}`. If `data.user` is a _string_, you are good or you should be using _any_.

Comment: ok that made the error disappear but would rather have user than message...it makes more sense for that line...but for the other lines i still want message...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244807/discussion-between-coderpc-and-preston).

Answer (score 0):

```
type Data = {
    message?: string
    user?: any
}
```

instead of just

```
type Data = {
    name: string
}
```